# Can't figure out what set these marvel-related bags belong to

Tags: set-identification

[image]

I can't figure out what set these bags go to. I see an Iron Man minifigure in one of the bags and the bag has 741R9 on it.

Comment: Note that the numbers on the bag don't give any help to us since there is no source we can use to identify the set using that number. If it had the actual set number then that would be better, but Lego never bothers to add that info on their bags unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

A distinctive items in Bag 1, [Trans-Light Blue -Dish 6 x 6 Inverted (Radar) Webbed  Type 2](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4285b&colorID=15&in=A), exists in 15 sets.  [2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76125-1#T=S&O=%7B"iconly":0%7D) of [these](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76107-1#T=S&O=%7B"iconly":0%7D) contain Iron Man

Of these [Set 76125-1: Iron Man Hall of Armor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76125-1#T=I) also contains the Bright Pink and Lime Green round 1x1 plates seen in Bag 3

[image: The assembled Lego set]

Comment: One of the things about BricksSE that still remain a big mystery to me is how you manage to find the exact set! Usually I just have to guess and look at the entire set to see if it looks somewhat similar, but it seems like you guys are using a special tool that looks for sets that have a specific group of parts (which obviously makes life easier)! *What is that tool you're using?!?*

Comment: @mindstormsboi [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com) - it has a good (but not *necessarily* complete) list of sets and parts.  Identify a part that looks like it might be uncommon, [do a search for it](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=dish%206%20x%206%20inverted#T=A), match the colour, and then look at the sets.  If there are too many sets with that part, try a different part.  Then, compare the Parts Lists.  In this case, the fact that I could quickly check if any of the sets were "Marvel" themed (i.e. might contain Iron Man) was a *big* help, so kudos to OP for including that.